# delphi xe file encryption

Tags: delphi, encryption, openssl

I'm looking for a file encryption solution that will work across platforms (win32, unix, mac) so I can create an encrypted version of a file in unix then decrypt it on win32 or mac.  Openssl works well on unix using aes 256.  Any ideas for how to decrypt on win32/mac?

Thanks

Comment: What does file encryption have to do with openssl? :-) Do you want to encrypt a FILE (7zip, etc) or TRANSMIT A FILE using encryption (scp)?

Comment: OpenSSL is cross-platform - it should work the same on Mac OS and Windows, too.

Comment: Of course OpenSSL is cross-platform. But it's a socket transport layer, not a file utility. Maybe this guy meant to say 'scp' (secure file copy?)

Comment: on unix you can type openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in file.txt -out file.out and the file gets encrypted

Comment: @WarrenP If it can encrypt buffers and streams it should also be able to encrypt files, or am I missing something?

Comment: Alan Grace : Hat tip to you, I had no idea you could use open ssl as a file encrypt tool.  +1.  And TOndrej, I was wrong. :-)

Answer (score 2):

[dcpcrypt](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/dcpcrypt) is a good option, I'm not sure if it works 100% under XE or XE2.

Comment: I ported it to 2009, and tested it on XE, and fine there too, but haven't tried it on XE2 yet.

Comment: thank you for that Warren! I've been using dcpcrypt in the past in D2010 and had no problem, however due to EMB's latest way of releasing stuff, we haven't upgraded to XE or XE2.

Answer (score 1):

For file encryption, have you considered 7Zip which uses AES-256? Then you can decrypt on any platform that supports 7zip, which includes Mac and Linux.  You could use the 7z.dll easily from Delphi.